# How to import bitarray using pypy?

Tags: python, importerror, python-import, pypy, bitarray

I am running [pypy](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/getting-started-python.html) and after adding the path to the bitarray library to `sys.path` I still can't import the module:

```
Python 2.7.3 (87aa9de10f9ca71da9ab4a3d53e0ba176b67d086, Feb 10 2014, 05:26:49)
[PyPy 2.2.1 with GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``every VM should come with neural
network trained to recognize microbenchmarks and randomly fluctuate them
+/-9000%''
>>>> import sys
>>>> sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/')
>>>> sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bitarray/')
>>>> import bitarray
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bitarray/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from bitarray._bitarray import _bitarray, bitdiff, bits2bytes, _sysinfo
ImportError: No module named bitarray._bitarray
```

In regular python (CPython installed from aptitude) importing bitarray works fine and I haven't made any modifications to the module after installing it with pip. What's wrong here?

Just in case you need it here is the content of the bitarray dir:

```
$ls  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bitarray/
_bitarray.so  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  test_bitarray.py  test_bitarray.pyc
```

**UPDATE**

After creating a virtualenv for pypy and installing bitarray with pip as Sunny suggested I still get an ImportError:

```
$ ls my-pypy-env/site-packages/bitarray
_bitarray.pypy-22.so  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  test_bitarray.py  test_bitarray.pyc


$ cd my-pypy-env/
~/my-pypy-env$ ./bin/activate 
~/my-pypy-env$ pypy
Python 2.7.3 (87aa9de10f9ca71da9ab4a3d53e0ba176b67d086, Feb 10 2014, 05:26:49)
[PyPy 2.2.1 with GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``__xxx__ and __rxxx__ vs operation
slots: particle quantum superposition kind of fun''
>>>> import sys
>>>> sys.path.append('/home/sofia/my-pypy-env/site-packages/bitarray')
>>>> import bitarray
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bitarray
```

**UPDATE 2**

Sunny's solution is correct. The new problem was appending `/site-packages/bitarray` 
instead of just `/site-packages/`. I would have though that virtualenv would add this to the path automatically but it seems that it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_bitarray` module looks like a CPython extension, which is written directly in `C`.
CPython extension modules does **not** work directly in PyPy without any changes. You either need to install PyPy compatible version of the module, or do the required changes manually.

To install pypy compatible version, use the following commands:

```
# If pypy is installed globally
/path/to/pypy/pypy-2.1/bin/pip install bitarray

# If using virtualenv
source /path/to/virtualenv/env/bin/activate
pip install bitarray
```

Here are a couple of links from PyPy FAQs about this issue:

http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#module-xyz-does-not-work-with-pypy-importerror

http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#do-cpython-extension-modules-work-with-pypy

Comment: Is there any way to make sure that bitarray is written in C?

Comment: Not the whole bitarray, but the submodule `bitarray._bitarray` in the ImportError.  Yes, it is: see the `.so` extension to the file `_bitarray.so`.

Comment: Note that running `pip install bitarray` in a virtualenv, as described in the links above, seems to work fine.  It compiles the C code successfully and you don't need to hack with sys.path.

Comment: I posted an update about this, I still get an ImportError after doing this

Comment: You have to do `source bin/activate` instead of `./bin/activate ` before starting pypy. [Reference](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#activate-script)

Comment: I did `chmod +x` to `activate` so `source` was not needed, this was not the problem. The problem was appending the bitarray folder. I've marked the question as answered, thanks!

Comment: If you do `source bin/activate`, then virtualenv would have added the path automatically. No need to modify sys.path